# Chef - Switch user and run package installations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife

I have a server that can only SSH using a non-admin username. I also have the root username and password for this server. I want to install some packages by bootstrapping this node. Is there a way to bootstrap this server and run the installations switching to root?

I ran the command,

```
knife bootstrap [NODE_IP] --ssh-user [NON-ROOT-USERNAME] --ssh-password [NON-ROOT-PASSWORD] --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name [NODE_NAME] --run-list 'recipe[bootstrap_test]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need user with sudo access to install packages which is different from running installations using root. Give the non-admin user sudo access in sudoers file. you can configure sudo access using command [visudo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos). 
Also see this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux)